# dtype: integer, but loc returns float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I have a weird data set:

```
   year   firms  age  survival
0  1977  564918    0       NaN
2  1978  503991    0       NaN
3  1978  413130    1  0.731310
5  1979  497805    0       NaN
6  1979  390352    1  0.774522
```

where I have cast the `dtype` of the first three columns to be integer:

```
>>> df.dtypes
year          int64
firms         int64
age           int64
survival    float64
```

But now I want to search in another table based on an index here:

```
idx = 331
otherDf.loc[df.loc[idx, 'age']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
(...)
KeyError: 8.0
```

This comes from

```
df.loc[idx, 'age']
8.0
```

Why does this keep returning a float value? And how can I perform the lookup in `otherDf`? I'm in pandas version `0.15`.

Comment: You can typecast the returned float to an integer for a quick fix, `int(df.loc[idx, 'age'])` which will give `>>> 8`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You get back a float because each row contains a mix of `float` and `int` types. Upon selecting a row index with `loc`, integers are cast to floats:

```
>>> df.loc[4]
year          1979.000000
firms       390352.000000
age              1.000000
survival         0.774522
Name: 4, dtype: float64
```

So choosing the `age` entry here with `df.loc[4, 'age']` would yield `1.0`.

To get around this and return an integer, you could use `loc` to select from just the `age` column and not the whole DataFrame:

```
>>> df['age'].loc[4]
1
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. I figured extending the test case in my answer by another column but was too lazy. Would have observed the same, hopefully.

Comment: I ran into this too just now, so thanks v much for the explanation.  Seems like a bug, no?  `loc[row, col]` has everything it needs to know that the return type should be an int.  Or is there some fundamental reason that this is really a "feature" rather than a bug?

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in pandas up through version 0.19.  It seems to have been fixed in version 0.20.  cf. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11617

Comment: I guess it has regressed in v1.0.3

Comment: Underway here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/37749

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use `loc`? What about this:

```
otherDf.loc(df['age'][idx])
```

Grabbing the value through the 'age' `Series` returns the appropriate type (`int64`)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce that behavior with Pandas 0.15.1.

```
>>> pd.__version__
'0.15.1'
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"age": [1,8]})
>>> df
   age
0    1
1    8
>>> df.dtypes
age    int64
dtype: object
>>> df.loc[1, "age"]
8
>>> type(df.loc[1, "age"])
<type 'numpy.int64'>
```

Spontaneously I could not find a relevant entry in the changelogs, but we may want to know whether you are using 0.15.0 or something newer.

**Edit:**

Adding another column with a float type indeed makes the row data type become normalized to float (as ajcr pointed out in his answer):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"age": [1, 8], "greatness": [0.2, 1.7]})
>>> type(df.loc[1, "age"])
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative now to use `df.at[idx, 'age']` when you need a single value.